# How to return multiple values from an Ajax request that is called in a promise chain

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, asynchronous, promise

I have been using promises to call asynchronous AJAX request functions that return API JSON objects for my geolocation app. I have been successful at this using the then() function to chain  and return each promise's data and use it accordingly.

The last Promise I want to use does not call an API it is a file which contains geodata. I have no problem returning this data but what I need to do is return the data and an additional variable from the last then() chain. Here is the last section of the code and the AJAX function.

```html
// ---- Following previous promise chain ---- //

return openWeather

}).then(function(data4) {

            console.log(data4)

            // Disregard this code

            $('#txtDescription').html(data4['data'][0]['weather']['description']);
            $('#txtSpeed').html(data4['data'][0]['wind_spd'] + ' mph');
            $('#txtDirection').html(data4['data'][0]['wind_dir'] + ' &deg;');
            $('#txtTemp').html(data4['data'][0]['temp'] + ' &deg; celcius');

            // I need to return this variable

            let iso2 = data4['data'][0]['country_code'];

            // I also need to return this function

            return geoData(iso2);

        }).then(function(result) {

            // I am trying to assigin two values from a returned array     

            let iso2 = result[0]
            let data5 = result[1]

            // Both console.logs read as undefined.

            console.log(iso2)
            console.log(data5);
```

I have my AJAX calls in another file and I am importing them as modules.

```html
function geoData(iso2) {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "countries.geo.json",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data5) {
            
            // both the variables log to the console here so I know they are being sent to the success function
            console.log(iso2)
            console.log (data5)

            // The only way I can think to return both values is to return an array.
            
            return [ iso2, data5 ]
        }
    });
};
```

I can return either the data from the 'geoData()' AJAX call or the 'iso2' variable, but not both. I basically need the variable to use in a conditional/loop that will compair with the returned JSON object and match it with a specific country.

Is it possible to return two values instead of just one? I would really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not how you return data from the ajax call. Instead of returning 2 values from an ajax call, you still return one value from the call, but 2 values from your function, like so:

```js
function geoData(iso2) {
  return $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1",
    dataType: 'json'
  }).then(data => [iso2, data]);
};

geoData("test").then(result => {
  console.log("result[0]", result[0]);
  console.log("result[1]", result[1]);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```